Issue with C# Program: .json File content is rigged
I’m facing a specific issue with a C# test program that navigates a website and takes screenshots of various pages and dialogs. These screenshots are saved in a .zip file, and at the end of a test, a sitemap.json file is created. This mechanism works fine, but the content of the .json file does not change. The .json file also has a timestamp - for example if i start a test today and tomorrow, the file content remains from todays´. The only solution is  to give the .json file a new name in the code (e.g., sitemap2.json), otherwise, it doesn’t change.
When I run multiple tests, the .zip file is always replaced and works correctly, but the sitemap.json file is also replaced but its content does not change. This means that if I run a test once and get a sitemap.json file, I always get exactly that same sitemap.json file again, even if I delete it and/or run a different test.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
   

    private void WriteSitemap()
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"d:\sitemap");
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Sitemap);
        var filePath = @"d:\sitemap\sitemap2.json";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json, Encoding.UTF8);
        var byteArray = GetScreenshotsZip();
        if (byteArray == null) return;
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\sitemap\sitemap-screenshots.zip", byteArray);
       
    }


Ensuring the file is overwritten: I checked that the file is deleted before writing.
Adding debugging statements: I added debugging statements to ensure the code that writes the file is actually executed.
Checking if the sitemap is updated correctly: I checked the content of the Sitemap before writing it.
Clearing the cache: I tried clearing the cache by deleting the file before writing and ensuring no old data is cached.
Restarting

Thank you in advance!
I hope this helps! Let me know if you need any further adjustments. 

"The .json file also has a timestamp" -- what timestamp? The file modified timestamp? File creating timestamp? A timestamp that you record somewhere inside the JSON file?

Are doing something with the files once generated and is the the file itself essentially temporary?

Please provide a [mcve] - if you're saying that File.WriteAllText undeletes a file instead of writing to it, I'm going to find that hard to believe without a way of reproducing it...

It's also very unclear what this has to do with selenium-webdriver, or testing, or automated-tests. Even if you happen to encounter this in testing, that doesn't mean it's really about testing.

Can you also share your implementation of GetScreenshotsZip?

Is it producing any exceptions or is it running completely?
make sure the file is deleted after delete line using:
Debug.Assert(!File.Exists(filePath), "File was not deleted successfully.");
Also check if the file is in read only mode, you can change that using like this:
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
if (fileInfo.Exists && fileInfo.IsReadOnly)
{
    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
}

